# Multer sftp file upload issue on node js

Tags: node.js

i m trying to upload a file local server to remote server, but am getting issue with upload a file into remote server also in my below code not getting error too.

```
var multer = require('multer')
var sftpStorage = require('multer-sftp')

var storage = sftpStorage({
  sftp: {
    host: 'ip address',
    port: '22',
    username: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'yyyyyyyyy'
  },
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, '/home/g457b5jxaq4m/public_html/shiva')
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) { return cb(null, '/home/sivaprakash/Desktop/cre.txt') }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

please kindly check my code and let me know if any mistake.

Comment: Please check whether the `port` => `22` is open or not

Comment: Also try changing your  `var upload = multer({ storage: storage })` statement as `var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');`

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Are there any logs for it?

Comment: @MihirKumar i did not get any error as of now. there is no log file created in the server.

Comment: @DavidR thanks for your suggesstion, still the file not getting uploading in the server. yes the port no 22 is opened.  i can able to upload fiel using https://preview.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client library not with the multer-sftp.

Comment: Thanks All, now I can upload a file in remote server. but I have another query now, if possible to change the destination path. If yes please let me know how I can achieve that please.